# Is it possible to assign a module to different objects and use variables of imported module in Python?

Tags: python

I created a module in Python, that simply sets variables(global). Let the file name of module created be date.py. It has int variables day, month, year

In another Python file, I import this module as:

import date

It is possible to access date variables if I use:

print(date.day)

but if I try to store date in different variables like:

Date1 = date(12,4,2012)
Date2= date(3,7,2021)

Now if I try to access particular object for comparison purposes, it is not being possible:
i.e:

if((Date1.day) == (Date2.day)):
pass

Is there a way to handle this usecase?

Comment: Use a class, not a module. A module is a singleton namespace in Python - you can't have multiple instances of a module. Better yet, you could use the [date class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) already provided by the standard library

Comment: add `__eq__` in `Date` class

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do a comparison on the date, year, or time because when we get data using direct function if follow her standard functionality like when we got data is: 25/07/2022 this kind of not possible.

If you still wish to do a comparison you can try to do it as first get date then get year inside on conditions like:

```py
if(day1 == day2):
    if(year1==year2):
        print(day.year)
    else:
        break
```

Maybe you can try this when you compare days and times as well.